# Yii2 - Get Current Action ID in main.php

Tags: yii2

In the file main.php at `views/layouts/main.php`, I want to add few classes to the body tag and add css class 'active' to the navigation bar items according to the view being displayed. Is there any way I can get action id in main.php?

I hope that html is not req

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In a layout you can access the current controller via `$this->context`, and so the current action id by `$this->context->action->id`

Answer (score 26):

Or you can use:

```
Yii::$app->controller->id // get controller name
```

to access the controller, and:

```
Yii::$app->controller->action->id // get action name
```

for getting the current action id. But put this directive at the top of file:

```
use Yii;
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is for Yii2?